# A tree of plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a collection of data that is hierarchical in nature, forming groups that would each be best plotted as a bar chart. If it's possible, I would love to be able to arrange a bunch of ggplot2 graphs so that they form a tree structure:
[image: bar plots forming a tree]

Is this something you can do with ggplot2 or supplemental package? The [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) package seems to be the closest but doesn't allow that amount of flexibility in positioning.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect a combination of `gridExtra` or related packages -- plus a bit of elbow grease -- might give you what you need. Having said that, you are asking us to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library"*, which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO. If you can come up with realistic code that demonstrates a starting point (using `patchwork` or something else), then your question will be more on-topic. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on how nested your data is and if you want to focus on some group more than others, you might also have some luck with `ggforce::facet_zoom` (scroll to near bottom [here](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2019/the-ggforce-awakens-again/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of packages `gridExtra` and `ggplot2`. To know more details I recommander look these vignettes: [Laying out multiple plots on a page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) and [Arranging multiple grobs on a page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html).

```
require(gridExtra)
require(ggplot2)

layout <- rbind(c(NA,1,1,NA),
              c(2,2,3,3))

p <- qplot(1,1)
p2 <- qplot(2,4)
p3 <- qplot(3,1)

grid.arrange(p, p2, p3,  layout_matrix=layout)
```

[image: Example]